# Black screen after build on a iOS 3 project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this iOS project for the iPhone written in Xcode 3.2.5 which worked fine under the simulator. But it doesnt work on the latest version of Xcode for some reason. I get this error when I compile it:
pinField is a text field by the way.
Any idea whats going on?

2012-08-29 01:54:46.232 Proj[3545:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pinField.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18a9022 0x127dcd6 0x18a8ee1 0xd3022 0x44f6b 0x44edb 0x5fd50 0x5a571a 0x18aadea 0x18147f1 0x5a426e 0x5a5eb7 0x382ce1 0x382ff8 0x38217f 0x391183 0x391c38 0x385634 0x1d9bef5 0x187d195 0x17e1ff2 0x17e08da 0x17dfd84 0x17dfc9b 0x381c65 0x383626 0x1d8a 0x1cd5)

Comment: Show us the line it is breaking on. There error is coming up because you are trying to set the value of pinField on an object that does not know what pinField is.

Comment: Oh right. Ok. It doesnt break on any line, but it tells me something about SIGBART or something in main.m. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Look for places in your code where you are trying to set a value for the key pinField.

Comment: I have just deleted everything to do with pinField. Now Im getting this error:http://pastebin.com/K9bUHTeJ

Comment: By the way, thanks for the speedy replies Sos :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have seen this earlier -> " Xcode 3.2.5" I THINK you are running into incompatibilities in the XIB files. That is my best guess.

Comment: Oh right... So does this mean I should redo all my XIBs?

Comment: Actually, I have tried it with another project from 3.2.5 and it worked fine.... I wonder whats going on.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit of a nag, but any ideas?